# Trying to compile clangs module example results in segmentation fault

Tags: c++, segmentation-fault, clang, c++-modules

When trying to compile the minimal working example for C++20 modules (taken from [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/StandardCPlusPlusModules.html)) the resulting binary results in a segmentation fault.

This is my code:

```cpp
// Hello.cppm
module;
#include <iostream>
export module Hello;
export void hello() {
  std::cout << "Hello World!" << std::endl;
}
```

```cpp
// use.cpp
import Hello;
int main() {
  hello();
  return 0;
}
```

I compiled everything using the following commands:

```bash
$ clang --version
clang version 14.0.6
Target: x86_64-pc-linux-gnu
Thread model: posix
InstalledDir: /usr/bin
$ clang++ -std=c++20 --precompile Hello.cppm -o Hello.pcm
$ clang++ -std=c++20 use.cpp -fprebuilt-module-path=. Hello.pcm -o Hello.out
```

`LLDB` outputs the following:

```
$ lldb ./Hello.out 
(lldb) target create "./Hello.out"
Current executable set to '/home/cwd/Hello.out' (x86_64).
(lldb) run
Process 160768 launched: '/home/cwd/Hello.out' (x86_64)
Process 160768 stopped
* thread #1, name = 'Hello.out', stop reason = signal SIGSEGV: invalid address (fault address: 0xffffffffffffffe8)
    frame #0: 0x00007ffff7e8168a libstdc++.so.6`std::ostream::sentry::sentry(this=0x00007fffffffd3d0, __os=0x00007ffff7f7b480) at ostream.tcc:51:19
(lldb) step
Process 160768 exited with status = 11 (0x0000000b)
```

**EDIT:** I forgot to mention that I'm compiling with `clang 14` on Linux.

Comment: Cannot reproduce with clang15. [Demo](https://godbolt.org/z/1oe6bjf97)

Comment: My general impression is that C++20 modules support is still not yet mature. I already found two _internal errors_ in MSVC 2022 while trying to migrate our code base to modules. I reported those bugs and Microsoft fixed them. But I am not surprised to see other problems with Clang also.

Comment: @n.m. Thanks for providing that demo. Interestingly enough, switching to clang 14 (the version I'm using) the segmentation fault occurs inside the online playground as well...

Comment: Apparently the demo is bogus, it doesn't compile the module as a .pcm precompiled module (add set(CMAKE_VERBOSE_MAKEFILE ON) to see the commands).